# how can i add links using java script

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to find the marquee option in javascript. and i would like to know how can i add hyperlink to this code?Can you please guide me..I am pasting the code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init() { rtl_marquee.start(); }
    var rtl_marquee_Text = 'text appear here';
    var rtl_marquee_Direction = 'left';
    var rtl_marquee_Contents='<span style="font-family:Comic Sans MS;font-size:8pt;white-space:nowrap;">' + rtl_marquee_Text + '</span>';
    rtl_marquee = new xbMarquee('rtl_marquee', '19px', '90%', 6, 100, rtl_marquee_Direction, 'scroll', rtl_marquee_Contents);
    window.setTimeout( init, 200);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can code like this...`var str = path + 'mypage.aspx?;
        javascript: window.open(str, 'SplPopup', 'scrollbars=yes,width=800,height=600,top=75,left=150,resizable=yes,status=yes,toolbar=no');`

Comment: Could you please edit in the above code and share to me? thanks